# Set time picker with specific Time Zone

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker

I am getting timezone from server as "GST".

How can I display current time in time picker in GST zone.

I am able to get by using ZoneID. But is there any ways to get proper time by timeZone("GST")

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get time zone by "GST"

```
 fun getTimeAsString(): String {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Qatar"))
    return sdf.format(Date())
}
```

List of Zone Ids:

https://gist.github.com/mtrung/a3f7caaa7e674ac7e6c4